# How can I turn off netty client DNS connect retry?

Tags: spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I'm using Netty-httpClient for Spring webClient.

When I connect `www.naver.com` and set the host like this.

```
127.0.0.1 www.naver.com
125.209.222.142 www.naver.com
```

And run `httpClient.get()` result like this.

```
 DEBUG r.n.r.PooledConnectionProvider - [id:83c8069f] Created a new pooled channel, now: 0 active connections, 0 inactive connections and 0 pending acquire requests.
 DEBUG r.n.t.SslProvider - [id:83c8069f] SSL enabled using engine sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@5412b204 and SNI www.naver.com:443
 DEBUG i.n.b.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
 DEBUG i.n.b.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
 DEBUG i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@7ec1e7a5
 DEBUG r.n.t.TransportConfig - [id:83c8069f] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.loggingHandler = reactor.netty.transport.logging.ReactorNettyLoggingHandler), (reactor.left.sslReader = reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
 INFO  reactor - [id:83c8069f] REGISTERED
 DEBUG r.n.t.TransportConnector - [id:83c8069f] Connecting to [www.naver.com/127.0.0.1:443].
 INFO  reactor - [id:83c8069f] CONNECT: www.naver.com/127.0.0.1:443
 INFO  reactor - [id:83c8069f] CLOSE
 DEBUG r.n.t.TransportConnector - [id:83c8069f] Connect attempt to [www.naver.com/127.0.0.1:443] failed.
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: www.naver.com/127.0.0.1:443
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:707)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 DEBUG r.n.r.PooledConnectionProvider - [id:0e3c272c] Created a new pooled channel, now: 0 active connections, 0 inactive connections and 0 pending acquire requests.
 DEBUG r.n.t.SslProvider - [id:0e3c272c] SSL enabled using engine sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl@47b241b and SNI www.naver.com:443
 DEBUG r.n.t.TransportConfig - [id:0e3c272c] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.loggingHandler = reactor.netty.transport.logging.ReactorNettyLoggingHandler), (reactor.left.sslReader = reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
 INFO  reactor - [id:0e3c272c] REGISTERED
 INFO  reactor - [id:83c8069f] UNREGISTERED
 DEBUG r.n.t.TransportConnector - [id:0e3c272c] Connecting to [www.naver.com/125.209.222.142:443].
 INFO  reactor - [id:0e3c272c] CONNECT: www.naver.com/125.209.222.142:443
 DEBUG r.n.r.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id:0e3c272c, L:/192.168.55.77:52910 - R:www.naver.com/125.209.222.142:443] Registering pool release on close event for channel
 DEBUG r.n.r.PooledConnectionProvider - [id:0e3c272c, L:/192.168.55.77:52910 - R:www.naver.com/125.209.222.142:443] Channel connected, now: 1 active connections, 0 inactive connections and 0 pending acquire requests.
 DEBUG i.n.u.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
 DEBUG i.n.u.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
 DEBUG i.n.u.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
 DEBUG i.n.u.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
 DEBUG i.n.u.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.delayedQueue.ratio: 8
 INFO  reactor - [id:0e3c272c, L:/192.168.55.77:52910 - R:www.naver.com/125.209.222.142:443] ACTIVE
```

see that. I don't want connect twice and don't spend more time to connect.
just fail if can not make connect.

Can I avoid this situation?

This is managing under the issue.
https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1822

Comment: nope, please create an enhancement issue ... :(

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva understood. I will create issue.